# Node JS require does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello i am working on this fix for 2-3 hours.. it was working at first, i moved some of my code to another file and required that file to make it cleaner then boom doesnt work anymore.

```
require('./mongooschema.js');

console.log(Mesaj);


/// SECOND FILE mongooschema.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://"""""""/"""""""');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mesajSchema = new Schema({
    mesaj: 'String',
    size: 'string'
});

var Mesaj = mongoose.model('Mesaj', mesajSchema);
module.exports = Mesaj;
```

Comment: Is `mongooschema.js` in same folder with the currently executing file?

Comment: Try `console.log(require('./mongooschema.js'))`

Comment: i tried console.log and it does work and paste the data of that file, yes its in the same folder.

Comment: If `require` do not work double check the name and the path of the required file (try to remove .js from the file)

Comment: require('./mongooschema'); Still same, i do require a file from same directory that works perfecly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you export something, then you must require() it to get to it.

In this case you can do.

```
var Mesaj = require('./mongooschema.js');

console.log(Mesaj);
```

If you simply require something like `require('./mongooschema.js');` withot assigning it to some variable, the contents of the required or exported file will be executed but the contents of the exports remains directly inaccessable. So if you add

`console.log(Mesaj)` before the export, it will get printed.

```
var Mesaj = mongoose.model('Mesaj', mesajSchema);
console.log(Mesaj);
module.exports = Mesaj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an interface with `module.exports`.

It isn't the same as other languages where it basically expands the file's contents there.

[Further reading](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: so i added this line to end of the file i included but still same..  "module.exports = Mesaj;"

Comment: @SezerYıldız And you then accessed it returned from your `require()` call?

Answer (score 0):

`require` function works like a function, it's not like `include` instruction in other languages.

So, to make it work you need:

- Export what you need using `module.exports` in your `mongooschema.js` file like this:

  ```
  module.exports = Mesaj
  ```
- Use `require` function result in your main file, which is `module.exports` content

  ```
  var Mesaj = require('./mongooschema.js');
  ```